# Defining 'Next Month' Date Range in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my VB application we can run reports based on various predefined date ranges, like 'this week' and 'last month'. I want to add a new range for 'next month'.

It seems that the existing date ranges we have defined are coded differently than the other solutions I have found so far. I've also tried variations that, I thought, were logical and could prove to be correct. Sadly, I have not yet succeeded.

The defined ranges we have currently in VB are formatted like this:

```
            Case 3 'This Week
            StartDate = Now.Date.AddDays(-Now.Date.DayOfWeek)
            EndDate = Now.Date.AddDays(6 - Now.Date.DayOfWeek)
        Case 4 'This Month
            StartDate = Now.Date.AddDays(-(Now.Day - 1))
            EndDate = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(Now.Year, Now.Month))
```

Comment: Do you want it to be inclusive or exclusive?  In other words, if it's currently Jan 17, 2019, would "next month" be a range of Feb. 1 - Feb. 28, or would it be Jan. 31 - Mar. 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Next month is easy:

```
Dim nexMonth = Date.Today.AddMonths(1)
StartDate = New Date(nexMonth.Year, nexMonth.Month, 1)
EndDate = StartDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1) ' or like you did in Case4 but with nexMonth
```

Comment: Much appreciated! As hard as I tried to fully comprehend what your code is actually saying I'm still at a loss. But, it worked, and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

Rango, you might have a problem with that logic if `Today` is March 31st, since the next month, April, has only 30 days.  But the fix is easy:

```
Dim startOfThisMonth = New Date(Date.Today.Year, Date.Today.Month, 1)
Dim nextMonth = startOfThisMonth.AddMonths(1)
```

... etcetera ...

In other words, first calculate the first day of the month that you are presently in, then compute your dates as you have shown from *that* day, rather than Today.

(And if Microsoft has already anticipated this such that your proferred solution would in fact be correct for any day, please excuse me.)

Comment: @Mike: Even if it's March 31st, if you use `AddMonths(1)` you dont get May as result but April 30st. `AddMonths` is clever enough that you don't get the after the next month if you say give me the next(`AddMonths(1)`).

Answer (score -1):

Some shared methods FWIW

```
Public Class DateRanges
    Public Class DateRange
        Public StartDate As Date
        Public EndDate As Date
    End Class

    Public Shared Function ThisWeek(d As Date) As DateRange
        Dim rv As New DateRange
        rv.StartDate = d.AddDays(-d.DayOfWeek)
        rv.EndDate = rv.StartDate.AddDays(6)
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Shared Function NextWeek(d As Date) As DateRange
        Dim rv As DateRange = ThisWeek(d)
        rv.StartDate = rv.StartDate.AddDays(7)
        rv.EndDate = rv.EndDate.AddDays(7)
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Shared Function PreviousWeek(d As Date) As DateRange
        Dim rv As DateRange = ThisWeek(d)
        rv.StartDate = rv.StartDate.AddDays(-7)
        rv.EndDate = rv.EndDate.AddDays(-7)
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ThisMonth(d As Date) As DateRange
        Dim rv As New DateRange
        rv.StartDate = d.AddDays(-d.Day + 1)
        rv.EndDate = rv.StartDate.AddDays(Date.DaysInMonth(rv.StartDate.Year,
                                                           rv.StartDate.Month) - 1)
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Shared Function NextMonth(d As Date) As DateRange
        Dim rv As DateRange = ThisMonth(d)
        rv.StartDate = rv.EndDate.AddDays(1)
        rv.EndDate = rv.StartDate.AddDays(Date.DaysInMonth(rv.StartDate.Year,
                                                           rv.StartDate.Month) - 1)
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Shared Function PreviousMonth(d As Date) As DateRange
        Dim rv As DateRange = ThisMonth(d)
        rv.EndDate = rv.StartDate.AddDays(-1)
        rv.StartDate = rv.EndDate.AddDays(-Date.DaysInMonth(rv.EndDate.Year,
                                                            rv.EndDate.Month) + 1)
        Return rv
    End Function
End Class
```

How to use

```
    Dim r As DateRanges.DateRange

    r = DateRanges.ThisWeek(Date.Now)
    r = DateRanges.NextWeek(#1/30/2019#)
    r = DateRanges.PreviousWeek(#1/30/2019#)
    r = DateRanges.ThisMonth(#1/30/2019#)
    r = DateRanges.NextMonth(r.StartDate)
    r = DateRanges.PreviousMonth(r.StartDate)
    r = DateRanges.NextMonth(Date.Now)
```